# How to do dependency parsing with custom lexicons

Tags: r, nlp

I have a load of medical text. I also have two lexicons. One contains a list of standardised anatomical locations eg `anatomy<-c("oesophagus", "stomach","duodenum", "pylorus", "antrum")` as well as a list of events `events<-c("clip","inject","emr","rfa")`.  The lists are actually much longer but I'm simplifying it here.

I would like to do dependency parsing on the medical text using the two lexicons so I can pick up events related to medical sites..for example:

**Input text**

The pylorus looked indurated. It underwent emr and rfa. The stomach started to bleed so a clip was placed. The bleeding stopped. Finally the oesophagus looked normal but the duodenum required a further clip

**Desired output 1**

which should give me:
 pylorus:emr, pylorus:rfa, stomach:clip, duodenum:clip

I think I have understood that I need to train a model using the lexicons and that this model needs to be provided in CONLL-U format (according to the [`udpipe`](https://bnosac.github.io/udpipe/docs/doc3.html) package. documentation). I might be wrong in assuming this however.

I have tried following the instructions but I do not know how to create the CONLL-U file in the first place using my lexicons. If I have misinterpreted how to do my custom dependency parsing please can you direct me to an explanation in r?...

As a further example, I have created a function in R that extracts elements from two lists if they are present in the same sentence, and another function if they are in adjoining functions. I have created this as part of a package I have written but here is the code:

**Dependency parsing attempts**

```
#' See if words from two lists co-exist within a sentence 
#'
#' See if words from two lists co-exist within a sentence. Eg site and tissue type.
#' This function only looks in one sentence for the two terms. If you suspect the terms may
#' occur in adjacent sentences then use the EntityPairs_TwoSentence function.
#' @keywords PathPairLookup
#' @param inputText The relevant pathology text column
#' @param list1 First list to refer to
#' @param list2 The second list to look for
#' @importFrom purrr flatten_chr map_chr map map_if
#' @export
#' @family Basic Column mutators 
#' @examples # tbb<-EntityPairs_OneSentence(Mypath$Histology,HistolType(),LocationList())

EntityPairs_OneSentence<-function(inputText,list1,list2){

  #dataframe<-data.frame(dataframe,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  list1<-paste0(unlist(list1,use.names=F),collapse="|")
  list2<-paste0(unlist(list2,use.names=F),collapse="|")

  #text<-textPrep(inputText)
  text<-standardisedTextOutput<-stri_split_boundaries(inputText, type="sentence")
  r1 <-lapply(text,function(x) Map(paste, str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(list2)), 
                                   str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(list1)), MoreArgs = list(sep=":")))

  r1<-lapply(r1,function(x) unlist(x))
  #Unlist into a single row-This should output a character vector
  out<-lapply(r1,function(x) paste(x,collapse=","))

  return(out)
}

#' Look for relationships between site and event
#' 
#' This is used to look for relationships between site and event especially for endoscopy events
#' where sentences such as 'The stomach polyp was large. It was removed with a snare' ie the therapy
#' and the site are in two different locations.
#' @keywords Find and replace
#' @param inputString The relevant pathology text column
#' @param list1 The intial list to assess
#' @param list2 The other list to look for
#' @importFrom stringr str_replace_na str_c str_split str_which str_extract_all regex str_subset
#' @importFrom stringi stri_split_boundaries
#' @importFrom rlang is_empty
#' @importFrom purrr flatten_chr map_chr map map_if
#' @export
#' @family Basic Column mutators 
#' @examples # tbb<-EntityPairs_TwoSentence(Myendo$Findings,EventList(),HistolType())

EntityPairs_TwoSentence<-function(inputString,list1,list2){

  #Prepare the text to be back into a tokenised version.
  #text<-textPrep(inputText)
  text<-standardisedTextOutput<-stri_split_boundaries(inputString, type="sentence")
  text<-lapply(text,function(x) tolower(x))


  #Some clean up to get rid of white space- all of this prob already covered in the ColumnCleanUp function but for investigation later
  text<-lapply(text,function(x) gsub("[[:punct:]]+"," ",x))
  #Prepare the list to use as a lookup:
  tofind <-paste(tolower(list2),collapse="|")

  #Prepare the second list to use as a lookup
  EventList<-unique(tolower(unlist(list1,use.names = FALSE)))


  text<-sapply(text,function(x) {

    #Cleaning
    x<-trimws(x)



    #Prepare the text so that all empty text is replaced with NA and 
    #ready for processing
    try(words <-
          x %>%
          unlist() %>%
          str_replace_na()%>%
          str_c(collapse = ' ') %>%
          str_split(' ') %>%
          `[[`(1))


    words<-words[words != ""] 
    x1 <- str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(paste(unlist(list1), collapse="|")))
    i1 <- which(lengths(x1) > 0)


    try(if(any(i1)) {
      EventList %>%
        map(
          ~words %>%
            str_which(paste0('^.*', .x)) %>%
            map_chr(
              ~words[1:.x] %>%
                str_c(collapse = ' ') %>%

                str_extract_all(regex(tofind, ignore_case = TRUE)) %>%
                map_if(rlang::is_empty, ~ NA_character_) %>%
                flatten_chr()%>%
                `[[`(length(.)) %>%

                .[length(.)]
            ) %>%
            paste0(':', .x)
        ) %>%
        unlist() %>%
        str_subset('.+:')

    } else "")

  }
  )
  return(text)
}
```

**Lexicons for the functions above**

The lexicons I am using for the two functions above are:

```
EventList <- function() {
  Event <- list(
    "radiofrequency ablation" = "RFA",
    "(argon plasma coagulation)|apc" = "APC",
    "halo| rfa" = "RFA",
    "dilatation|dilated" = "dilat",
    "clip" = "clip",
    "grasp" = "grasp",
    "iodine" = "iodine",
    "acetic" = "acetic",
    "NAC" = "NAC",
    "Brushings" = "brushings",
    " cryo" = "cryablation"
  )

  # To get the list as a list of values only in a regex use
  # paste0(unlist(Event,use.names=F),collapse="|")

  return(Event)
}


HistolType <- function() {

  # First standardise the terms

  tissue <- list(
    "Resection" = "Resection",
    "bx|biopsies" = "Biopsy",
    "(endoscopic mucosal resection)|(endoscopic mucosectomy)" = "EMR",
    "endoscopic submucosal (dissection|resection)" = "ESD",
    "nodul" = "nodul",
    "polyp" = "polyp",
    "emr" = "EMR"
  )


  # To get the list as a list of values only in a regex use
  # paste0(unlist(HistolType(),use.names=F),collapse="|")

  return(tissue)
}
```

**A larger synthetic example dataset is given here:**

```
c("OESOPHAGUS: tight proximal anastomotic stricture - dilated 20mm\n,STOMACH: minimal non-erosive gastritis - CLO test negative\n,Flumazenil given\n,This couldn't be resolved with the coag graspers so 2 clips were deploted over the vessel and 1:10,000 adrenaline x10ml was injected with haemostasis achieved\n,Oesophagus and stomach normal\n,Stomach- Antrum Gastritis- Nodular\n,Normal duodenum\n,There was loss of pit pattern on surface,STOMACH: significant amount of food residue in the stomach, therefore the procedure was stopped due to risk of aspiration and poor views\n,Examined under white light and NBI\n\n\n",
 Duodenum treated with HALO RFA Channel at 12J\n,Sliding hiatus hernia 3cm, GOJ biopsies taken\n,Intubation of efferent limb for a length of the scope\n,Linear erosions in oesophagus\n,OESOPHAGUS: Normal to GOJ at 41 cm\n,\n,Treated with HALO 90 RFA at 12J\n\n\n"
    )
```

**And the desired output 2:**

```
[[1]]
[1] "Oesophagus:dilat"  "stomach:clip"   "stomach:grasp" 

[[2]]
[1] "Duodenum:rfa" "Oesophagus:rfa"
```

Comment: A few questions. Could you create a slightly better (and bigger) example? How do you get your desired output, what rules do you see? e.g. oesophagus would be found, and would get a dependency with the event list as it is in the same sentence with duodenum. Probably have some more when I see your answers.

Comment: @jwijffels do you have any suggestions?